# Android ble RN4020 app not showing the available devices in some mobile brands

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

Android app developed for ble RN4020 is not detecting the bluetooth in some mobile brands.

It is working fine in Micromax and Asus.

Comment: in which devices ,its not detecting can you name them

Comment: Redmi devices,moto almost most of the devices

Comment: i already done this in moto-G ,its working fine.did your location is ON or not ?

Comment: location is turned off in mobile..

Comment: even after turning the location ON it is scanning and does not find the device

Comment: is your Micromax and Asus has marshmello ?

Comment: no they are not marshmallow

Comment: As of my experience with BLE, it must detect on Redmi as well. So please Install any other BLE app from play store on the phone that does not detecting the ble presence and check is it the issue with phone or your code.

Comment: It prompts me to enable gps location..how do i enable gps location on / off option in android? Like the one prompts us to connect the bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

If You're working with Android API 23 and up you need a runtime permission in your app. The permission in the AndroidManifest is not enough.
Hope this will help